# setting a value in a specific position in an empty matrix using numpy python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have an issue with setting a value in an empty numpy 3D Matrix
here is a simplified example of the code that I am using

```
import numpy as np

QMatrix = np.empty(((3,3,3))) # I do not want to use np.zero for a specific reason
QMatrix[0][0][0] = 57
print ("Position Values is " , Qmatrix[0][0][0])
```

This should set the value 57 @ [0][0][0] position of the matrix but when I print the matrix all I am getting is

```
Position Value is 5.70000000e+001
```

But what I want is that the value to be at as 57

any help would be appriciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: pass `dtype=np.int` as a second argument to `np.empty`

Comment: Thanks @YakymPirozhenko but when I do that all the other values also become very large. but I do not want that to happen as well

Answer (score 0):

you must edit second line from

```
QMatrix = np.empty(((3,3,3)))
```

to

```
QMatrix = np.empty(((3,3,3)), dtype=int)
```

your script will be :

```
import numpy as np
QMatrix = np.empty(((3,3,3)), dtype=int) #QMatrix = np.empty(((3,3,3))) 
QMatrix[0][0][0] = 57
```

Comment: Thanks @Hamza but when I do that all other values gets big as well

Answer (score 0):

The default dtype of numpy array is `float64`. You can verify this in your code by

```
import numpy as np
QMatrix = np.empty(((3,3,3)))
print QMatrix.dtype
```

Outputs - `dtype('float64')`

So, If you want the array to be of integer type, you need to set `dtype` explicitly while declaring numpy array

```
QMatrix = np.empty(((3,3,3)),dtype='int')
print QMatrix.dtype
```

Outputs - `dtype('int64')`

Now, if you try to assign first element of 3-D array i.e. `QMatrix[0][0][0] = 57` it will be stored as `int` type not `float`.

.

Comment: Thank you. But If I do that my other values in the vector gets big as well.